# Phpstorm codestyle's put new newlines

Tags: php, phpstorm

how can i define PhpStorm code styling to put new lines for eg

```
if($foo == 'bar') {
    //do this
}
```

to be

```
if($foo == 'bar')
{
    //do this
}
```

i remember this being in earlier version but i cant find it in 7.1 please help

Answer (score 1):

You should go to `Settings -> Code style -> PHP ->Wrapping and Braces`, then expand `Braces placement` and for `Other` you should choose `Next line`

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that by going into Settings » [Project settings] » Code Style » PHP.
Next, select tab "Wrapping and Braces" and at the top you will see the group "Braces placement".

In this group you could set "Other" to "Next line"